# The converse of Euler's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

ㅑn the strict sense, the Euler's Theorem is saying that
If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ , then $x = \phi(n)$ can be solution of $a^x \equiv 1\pmod n$. The question is:

> If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ and $a^x \equiv 1\pmod n$, then $x = k\phi(n)$ ($k\in\mathbb N$) are the only solutions of the equation?

Comment: Just pick $a=1$ to see that this cannot hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general. For instance, if $n=7$ and $a=2$, then you have $2^3\equiv1\pmod 7$. However, $\varphi(7)=6$ and $6\nmid3$.